# Difficulty understanding the value of removing arrow functions () =>

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I search the internet for `react-native` optimizations / best practices (**Especially for `FlatLists` which are often greedy**), I always find the advice not to use the arrow functions `<Component onPress={() => ... }`.

*Example 1 :* https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration#avoid-anonymous-function-on-renderitem :

> Move out the renderItem function to the outside of render function, so it won't recreate itself each time render function called. (...)

*Example 2 :* https://blog.codemagic.io/improve-react-native-app-performance/ :

> Avoid Arrow Functions : Arrow functions are a common culprit for wasteful re-renders. Don’t use arrow functions as callbacks in your functions to render views (...)

*Example 3 :* https://medium.com/wix-engineering/dealing-with-performance-issues-in-react-native-b181d0012cfa :

> Arrow functions is another usual suspect for wasteful re-renders. Don’t use arrow functions as callbacks (such as click/tap) in your render functions (...)

I understand that it is recommended not to use arrow function (especially in `onPress` button and `FlatList`), and to put the components outside of the render if possible.

**Good practice example :**

```
const IndexScreen = () => {    
  const onPress = () => console.log('PRESS, change state, etc...')

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        onPress={onPress}
      />
      <FlatList
        ...
        renderItem={renderItem}
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
      />
    </>
  )
}

const renderItem = ({ item: data }) => <Item data={data} ... />
const renderFooter = () => <Footer ... />

export default IndexScreen
```

But, often, I have other properties to integrate into my child components. The arrow function is therefore mandatory:

```
const IndexScreen = () => {
  const otherData = ...(usually it comes from a useContext())...

  <FlatList
    ...
    renderItem={({ item: data }) => renderItem(data, otherData)}
  />
}

const renderItem = (data, otherData) => <Item data={data} otherData={otherData} />

export default IndexScreen
```

In the latter situation, are good practices followed despite the presence of an arrow function ?
In summary, if I remove `otherData` (for simplicity), are these two situations strictly identical and are good practices followed ?

**Situation 1 :**

```
const IndexScreen = () => {    
  return (
    <FlatList
      ...
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
  )
}

const renderItem = ({ item: data }) => <Item data={data} ... />

export default IndexScreen
```

**=== Situation 2 ?**

```
const IndexScreen = () => {    
  return (
    <FlatList
      ...
      renderItem={({ item: data }) => renderItem(data)}
    />
  )
}

const renderItem = (data) => <Item data={data} ... />

export default IndexScreen
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first situation is ideal, because when your app code runs it will create only one `renderItem` function. In the second situation, even if it doesn't have otherProps, you're not following the good practice because a new function is created every render in this line

```
renderItem={({ item: data }) => renderItem(data)}
```

Hence, making the FlatList rerender every time.

To fix it, you need to memoize the function you pass in the `renderItem` prop with `useCallback`

```
const renderItem  = useCallback(({ item: data }) => {
   return (<Item data={data} />)
}, []);

...

    <FlatList
      ...
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
```

so the memoized version will be created only once when the component mounts. And, if you need to inject more data in the render function, you define that data as a dependency of the `useCallback` hook to create the function only when that data changes, reducing rerenders down the tree.

```
const renderItem  = useCallback(({ item: data }) => {
   return (<Item data={data} otherData={otherData} />)
}, [otherData]);
```

Answer (score 11):

The answer has nothing to do with arrow functions, but rather understanding reference equality why react might decide to rerender a component.

You can use useCallback to wrap your function. This will cause the reference to renderItem to only update when one of your callback dependencies updates.

```
const renderItem = useCallback(()=>{
...
},
[otherdata]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :)
Are you sure this is the only reason? I am familiar with `useCallback` / `useMemo` and `PureComponent`, I know they should be used with caution. Arrow functions are however always not recommended (as evidenced by my three quotes), regardless of `useCallback`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the arrow syntax. React will re-render a component whenever a reference changes to a prop or state. If you are recreating a function on every render then passing that new reference down as a prop into a child component, that child will re-render too. useCallback will only return a new reference to its first param when the dependencies update. Creating the function outside of the render loop (like in the module) will only create a single reference to that function (or I guess whever the module is loaded).

Answer (score 0):

to me as pointed out previously in other answers the issue is mainly due to the fact that if you use arrow functions inside the code, the function get redefined every time.
Also this way of defining a function make this function unnamed so this is harder to track while debugging: on error stack trace you can see the name of a named function directly in the code.

```
const renderItem  = useCallback( function renderItemFunction ({ item: data }) {
   return (<Item data={data} otherData={otherData} />)
}, [otherData]);
```

this way in the stack trace of errors you should see `renderItemFunction` indication